# 'Newtonsoft' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, json.net, nuget

I pasted the code from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/789481/Bridging-the-Gap-between-Linqpad-and-Visual-Studio into Visual Studio 15. It tells me that 'Newtonsoft' could not be found. I open the folder "\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies" and found that the file Newtonsolft.Json.dll is already there. Could anyone tell me how to fixed problem?

---

[image]

Comment: Can u please add a screenshot of your references from Solution Explorer?

Comment: have you added the NuGet package reference? https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Solution Explorer->Right Click on Project Name -> Click on Manage Nuget Packages -> Search for newtonsoft -> Click on install button

Comment: what if it is already installed and it cannot be uninstalled because it depend on other (to me unknown) .dlls ?

Comment: because i though new installation will resolve the problem, i updated the package but iam still getting the same error as asker

Comment: Do you have reference added for NewtonSoftJSon.dll in your project?

Answer (score 13):

Go to Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

[image]

and in the console just write `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 9.0.1`

[image]

Comment: Works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

For me I had the package already installed but it was missing the references and it could not be added.
Helped me: in `NuGet` Package Manager to downgrade and upgrade `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: Oh man I wish I had seen this before I wasted a half a day on this. THANK YOU for this answer.

Answer (score 7):

You have to get the correct NuGet package. From your link:

[image]

You can open the NuGet package manager in: `Tools -> Nuget Packet Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution..`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and Google API's had a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json, not allowing me to uninstall Newtonsoft.Json and trying to reinstall.

Removing and and reinstalling Newtonsoft.Json will likely solve the problem, but in my situation, I had to go into Nuget Package Manager -> find Newtonsoft.Json -> select Options dropdown -> check "Force uninstall even if there are dependencies on it".

Checking that box allowed me to remove and subsequently reinstall Newtonsoft and the solution properly referenced it after.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with visual studio 2019. Simply restarting visual studio fixed the issue. 
After restarting, the References list in Solution Explorer did show the "Newtonsoft.json".

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the **client** project side and select Manage NuGet packages.
Then search for **Newtonsoft.Json** on browse and install.
If the class you are trying to use Newtonsoft is in client you must install the package for the client.

Answer (score 0):

In case if answers above didn't help you, try to remove the links to `Newtonsoft` from your `.csproj` files, for me it helped.

Before this I tried to remove `packages` folder, tried to remove `.nuget` cache, remove and install Newtonsoft with `--force` flag as it is described above but nothing helped for me. Removing from .csproj and reinstalling helped me. I am using VS Community 2022.