# Pinging in c# (uwp)

Tags: c#, uwp, pinging

I'm trying to create a universal windows platform c# program that includes a network map.

UWP c# doesn't include any built in pinging tools and `system.net.pinging` won't install. How can I ping using the `windows.network.sockets` namespace to find out what computers are on the network (and their MAC address, hostname and hopefully operating system).

Answer (score 2):

[System.Net.Ping 4.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Ping/) Provides the System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping class, which allows an application to determine whether a remote computer is accessible over the network.

Add the `System.Net.Ping` NuGet package to your project using

```
Install-Package System.Net.Ping -Version 4.0.0
```

in [Package Manager Console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416621/3796048)

Comment: Doesn't work here's the error:                                                              Install-Package : Project 'Default' is not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.Net.Ping -Version 4.0.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: I can install others

Comment: I did and tried to upvote your answer but I don't have the reputation

Comment: Actually there is some issue with Ping NuGet. See [System.Net.Ping NuGet Installation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538754/system-net-ping-nuget-installation-error) asked just 2 hours ago.