# JsonReaderException being throw trying to parse a JSON file that contains several JSON objects inside [C#]

Tags: c#, json

I exported from Azure IoT Central to a Blob Storage a file containing several JSON objects (36 objects) within that same file.

The below are the first 2 lines from that file

> `{"applicationId":"appID","component":"thermostat1","deviceId":"usingTemControllerTemplate","enqueuedTime":"2022-03-21T15:31:38.687Z","enrichments":{},"messageProperties":{},"messageSource":"telemetry","schema":"default@v1","telemetry":{"temperature":23.2},"templateId":"urn:modelDefinition:tczx6jwcwz1:h2httvyo48g"}`
>
> `{"applicationId":"appID","component":"thermostat2","deviceId":"usingTemControllerTemplate","enqueuedTime":"2022-03-21T15:31:38.703Z","enrichments":{},"messageProperties":{},"messageSource":"telemetry","schema":"default@v1","telemetry":{"temperature":16.9},"templateId":"urn:modelDefinition:tczx6jwcwz1:h2httvyo48g"}`

I created 2 classes to show the heirarchy in the JSON objects. RootObject & Telemetry.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string applicationId { get; set; }
    public string component { get; set; }
    public string deviceId { get; set; }
    public string enqueuedTime { get; set; }
    public string messageSource { get; set; }
    public string schema { get; set; }
    public List<Telemetry> telemetry { get; set; }
    public string templateId { get; set; }
}

public class Telemetry
{
    public double temperature { get; set; }
}
```

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777114) and modeled it to my specific heirarchy and tried to make it work. However, a JsonReaderException is being thrown I run it in Visual Studio.
This is the code I'm running:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string filePath = "~pathToFile";
RootObject rt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(filePath);

if (rt.telemetry[1].temperature == 23.2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rt.telemetry[1].temperature);
}
```

The `JsonReaderException` is being thrown on this line:

```
RootObject rt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(filePath);
```

In the below image is the message being shown:
[image: JsonReaderException thrown]

Could someone please help me find the cause of this issue and how I could resolve it?

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` expect contents, not a file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is not a list/array of objects, it's a 36 lines with each line containing json for a single object.

With this observation we can:

```
List<RootObject> list = new();
foreach(var line in lines.Where( l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)))
{
   RootObject? o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(line);
   if (o != null)
   {
     list.Add(o); 
   }
}
```

`telmetry` is an object, not a list so you need to also change the RootObject definition:

```
    "telemetry": {
        "temperature": 23.2
    },
```

```
public class RootObject
{
    ...
    public Telemetry telemetry { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hello.
It is still giving me the same exception.
"Error parsing comment. Expected: *, got U. Path '', line 1, position 1."

Comment: OK, I had an obvious error there. The read should be from `(line)`. I also added some defensives.

Comment: Ohh I also didn't notice that 'line' wasn't used. It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

first of all the **JSON format is wrong**, it looks like this (see below) and
secondly he **doesn't want to have the File path** but **the json (value)**, so you have to read it in
and what is also very important. **You have 2 elements of "RootObject"**,
that means you have to put into a Array or List<> of RootObjects

Code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//reads the file and saves into a string
string jsonValue = File.ReadAllText("~pathToFile");

//Deserialize the objects and put them in a list of "RootObject".
List<RootObject> rt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonValue);
```

correct JSON format:

```
[
     {
          "applicationId": "appID",
          "component": "thermostat1",
          "deviceId": "usingTemControllerTemplate",
          "enqueuedTime": "2022-03-21T15:31:38.687Z",
          "enrichments": {},
          "messageProperties": {},
          "messageSource": "telemetry",
          "schema": "default@v1",
          "telemetry": {
               "temperature": 23.2
          },
          "templateId": "urn:modelDefinition:tczx6jwcwz1:h2httvyo48g"
     },
     {
          "applicationId": "appID",
          "component": "thermostat2",
          "deviceId": "usingTemControllerTemplate",
          "enqueuedTime": "2022-03-21T15:31:38.703Z",
          "enrichments": {},
          "messageProperties": {},
          "messageSource": "telemetry",
          "schema": "default@v1",
          "telemetry": {
               "temperature": 16.9
          },
          "templateId": "urn:modelDefinition:tczx6jwcwz1:h2httvyo48g"
     }
]
```

Comment: Hello. The previous exception has been resolved now but there's a new exception now:
"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RootObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.

Comment: [Continuation of the exception]:
JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\nPath 'applicationId', line 1, position 17."

Comment: Has the error been corrected because above there is already a correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix json, by converting it to array of objects

```
    var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    json = "[" + json.Replace("\n\r",",")+"]";

    List<RootObject> lrt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
    
    double[] telemetries=rt.Select(r => r.telemetry.temperature ).ToArray(); // [23.2,16.9]
    
    double telemetry=rt.Where(t=> t.telemetry.temperature==23.2)
                            .Select(r =>r.telemetry.temperature ).FirstOrDefault(); //23.2
```

and fix class too, telemetry should be an object, not a list

```
public class RootObject
{
    ....
    public Telemetry telemetry { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello. The previous exception has been resolved but there's a new exception now:
"After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {. Path '[0]', line 2, position 0."

Comment: @J.Z  I tested the code using a json you posted. It means that you posted a wrong json. Post the real one in other I could correct my code.