# Deserialize dynamic object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch Facebook profile data through Graph API. I am using Facebook SDK in MVC application. Using the following code returns dynamic result.

```
dynamic myInfo = await fb.GetTaskAsync("v2.8/me?fields=first_name,last_name,link,locale,email,name,birthday,gender,location,age_range");
      var facebookProfile = new FacebookProfileViewModel()
                {
                    FirstName = myInfo.first_name,
                    LastName = myInfo.last_name,
                    LinkUrl = myInfo.link,
                    Locale = myInfo.locale };
```

I am getting the data from facebook like this -

```
[{"Key":"first_name","Value":"John"},{"Key":"last_name","Value":"Doe"},{"Key":"link","Value":"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/4327693/"}]
```

I am getting the following error -

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Facebook.JsonObject' to 'string'
```

Answer (score 1):

Install newtonsoft:

[Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416621/3796048)

Convert from json:

```
string json = 
"[
    {
        "Key": "first_name",
        "Value": "John"
    },
    {
        "Key": "last_name",
        "Value": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "Key": "link",
        "Value": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/4327693/"
    }
]";
FbProfile Profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FbProfile>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you Mohit. It does not work, I have tried to bind with my ViewModel.

Comment: not work because Expected json result

{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","link":"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/4327693/"}

Comment: @snnbrn this is also a valid json. Lemme format it to show how it looks like