# how to install GDAL into visual studio for c# on windows?

Tags: c#, gdal

I'm gonna use GDAL into visual studio for c# on windows.
And followed some steps through some posts.
However, it seems it doesn't work between steps and, the biggest problem is that it can't build and install.

I will explain how to install, then if any of you knows and let me know why i can't install it, it will be so helpful.

1. to download:
   Stable Releases, GDAL2.1.2 and MapServer 7.0.2, MSVC 2013/x64(mine:64), gdal-201-1800-x64-core.msi.
   link: http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1800-x64-gdal-2-1-2-mapserver-7-0-2.zip
2. to set up paths:
   System -> Advanced system settings -> System Properties -> Environment Variables =>
   Edit System Variable: Path, C:\Program Files\GDAL\csharp
   Add System Variable: GDAL, C:\Program Files\GDAL
   (i also add two more: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins, C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data with names)
3. I downloaded a sample to test this environment setting.
   (http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps/GDALInfo.cs)
4. (visual studio 2013)Add four of the dll-files(gdal_csharp.dll, gdalconst_csharp.dll, ogr_csharp.dll and osr_csharp.) to my project references from C:\Program Files\GDAL\csharp(there was no gdalconst_cshap.dell though, i download it from a site i found).
5. Change Platform target to x64 in Properties.
6. Run the program.
   1) nothing happened.
   2) in the case, i forced to change the running goes to Gdal.AllRegister() to chech if GADL and VS are linked though, it said "The type initializer for 'OSGeo.GDAL.GdalPINVOKE' threw an exception."

// I know there must be something i missed during process, but i think for now i can't find anymore. any help or hints or suggestion will be very welcomed!

Comment: i checked below sites: http://vipassanaandenvironmentalinformatics.blogspot.kr/2013/03/getting-started-with-c-and-gdal.html, https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnWindows, https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows, http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/, http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php, http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps/GDALInfo.cs

Comment: Did you try [GDAL 1.11.1 NuGet from Package Manager Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GDAL/) for NuGet. You can have a look at [How to use Package Manager Console](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40416621/3796048)

Comment: I just tried it as your kind reply though, the result hasn't changed. I still wonder if I installed it in right way.