# How to parse strange json object from api in C#

Tags: c#, json, azure

I am working with an azure mobile app and it returns json data with a format I cannot read.
The sting is acquired using

```
var newMember = new Member() { Id = Settings.UserId };
var url = azureService.Client.MobileAppUri + ".auth/me";
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", Settings.AuthToken);
var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
dynamic responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

responseBody is

```
"[
  {
    \"id_token\": \"tokenstring\",
    \"provider_name\": \"aad\",
    \"user_claims\": [
      {
        \"typ\": \"exp\",
        \"val\": \"903i4231\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"nbf\",
        \"val\": \"123516345294\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"ver\",
        \"val\": \"1.0\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"iss\",
        \"val\": \"https: \\\/\\\/login.microsoftonline.com\\\/somestring\\\/v2.0\\\/\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"http: \\\/\\\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\\\/ws\\\/2005\\\/05\\\/identity\\\/claims\\\/nameidentifier\",
        \"val\": \"someotherstring\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"aud\",
        \"val\": \"anotherstringstill\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"nonce\",
        \"val\": \"stringy\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"iat\",
        \"val\": \"3543345\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"http: \\\/\\\/schemas.microsoft.com\\\/ws\\\/2008\\\/06\\\/identity\\\/claims\\\/authenticationinstant\",
        \"val\": \"6363456345\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"http: \\\/\\\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\\\/ws\\\/2005\\\/05\\\/identity\\\/claims\\\/givenname\",
        \"val\": \"FIRSTNAME?\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"http: \\\/\\\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\\\/ws\\\/2005\\\/05\\\/identity\\\/claims\\\/surname\",
        \"val\": \"LastName?\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"http: \\\/\\\/schemas.microsoft.com\\\/identity\\\/claims\\\/identityprovider\",
        \"val\": \"google.com\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"http: \\\/\\\/schemas.microsoft.com\\\/identity\\\/claims\\\/objectidentifier\",
        \"val\": \"somestringelse\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"emails\",
        \"val\": \"address@gmail.com\"
      },
      {
        \"typ\": \"tfp\",
        \"val\": \"B2C_1_ScoreSignupIn\"
      }
    ],
    \"user_id\": \"useridstring\"
  }
]"
```

How can I convert this to a useful C# object so I can get the string `Firstname?` and `LASTNAME?`

I tried

```
string firstName = responseJson.claims.givenname;
```

to no avail.
Also, what is this type of JSON called. I remember reading about it while learning about azure API but I cannot remember where. I don't even know what to call it to search it up. Also the json prettyprints at [jsonprettyprint.com](http://jsonprettyprint.com/json-pretty-printer.php) but I cannot convert it to a C# object using http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: The actual message is valid json I changed the values in there since it is filled with tokens all over the place that I am removed. I'll try to edit it again so the json is valid.

Comment: You are not able to convert to parse this json and convert it object, Right?

Comment: This specific object got mangled when I tried to remove private data from it. However the compiler does not complain when parsing the response from the server. I just don't understand how to get the data out of the object.

Comment: Use Newtonsoft Nuget package and try the way that @Mohit posted as an answer.

Comment: That worked thanks. I still don't understand the formatting for this json. are all of the `/` escape characters or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416621/3796048) and then this is what you can do to find the values from the JSON

```
string jsn = File.ReadAllText("YourJSON.txt");
List<RootObject> ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsn);
foreach(UserClaim uc in ro[0].user_claims)
{
    if(uc.val=="FIRSTNAME")
    {
        //Do whatever you want.
    }
    //or
    if(uc.typ.Contains("givenname"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(uc.val);
    }


}
```

This will be the classes for your JSON

```
public class UserClaim
{
    public string typ { get; set; }
    public string val { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id_token { get; set; }
    public string provider_name { get; set; }
    public List<UserClaim> user_claims { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 

dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>("{ \"test\":\"some data\" }");

string test= item["test"];
```

Replace this

> "{ \"test\":\"some data\" }"

with your JSON string.

You can also specify the exact data type instead of object and dynamic variables.

Comment: Even though Mohit's solution worked I want ot try your suggestion to understand this better. By doing your recommendation is it possible to get the value of such a complicated object without looping?

Comment: That produced the error `System.ArgumentException: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "user_claims". Array position index expected.` I used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>()` Since I could not find an object by the name JavascriptSerializer.

Comment: I just meant that U should try to write "List<RootObject> ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsn);" write "RootObject" instead of dynamic and List<RootObject> instead of object.

Comment: This line is same as mohit has mentioned. :)

Comment: Oh ok. ``System.Collections.Generic.List<ScoreContraception.Helpers.RootObject>.this[int]' has some invalid arguments` is the result this time. Are you sure you aren't thinking of Javascript for that last bit? I know you can accesss object properties using array notation in JS but it doesn't seem to be working C#.

Comment: Let me provide you the exact syntax i.e List<RootObject> item = serializer.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(YouJsonString); 
You will get the list of object's in item and You can iterate it to get the required Output

Comment: That's what I did. `string test= item["test"];` seems  to be the problem. Specifically the use of a string in the `[]`rather than and int.

Comment: No. I think you misunderstood what I told. If you specify the type instead of object and dynamic keyword. You will get an object of that type.In our case we will write `List<RootObject> items = serializer.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(YouJsonString);` so we will get list of RootObject as an output. So to get the value we need to iterate this list. You cannot get values by `string test= item["test"]`. To  get value You can do as 
`foreach(var item in items)
{
 var tk = item.id_token;
 var claims = item.user_claims;
 foreach(var claim in user_claims){
  var typ = claim.typ;
 }
}`

Comment: Oh ok thanks for your patience and information. It is possible to do test = item["test"] in JavaScript. So I though you meant that that would also work somehow in C # as well.

Comment: No problem friend :)