# Retrieving value from a JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to retrieve `Value`'s using `Key`'s in the `JSON` returned.

I tried the following but, none worked.

1.)

```
string email= json.emailAddress;
```

2.)

```
string email= json["emailAddress"].ToString();
```

**Complete Code**

```
 var api= new Uri("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?format=json");
 using (var webClient = new WebClient())
 {
       webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);

       webClient.Headers.Add("x-li-format", "json");

       dynamic  json = webClient.DownloadString(api);
  }
```

JSON returned

```
{
  "emailAddress": "xxxx@xx.com",
  "firstName": "xxx",
  "formattedName": "xxxx xxxx",
  "id": "xxxxxx",
  "lastName": "xxxxxx",

}
```

Comment: There are times when `dynamic` is good to use, but when you know the return type of a method you should declare the variable of that type, i.e. `string json = webClient.DownloadString(api);`. Using `dynamic` doesn't give your variable magical properties - if it's a `string` it's still a `string` with `dynamic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question using your approach, the simplest way ( without using JSON.Net ) is to use the `JavaScriptSerializer`

```
// have this at the top with your using statements
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

and in your code, use `JavaScriptSerializer` as shown below.

```
var api= new Uri("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?format=json");
 using (var webClient = new WebClient())
 {
     webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);    
     webClient.Headers.Add("x-li-format", "json");
    string json = webClient.DownloadString(api);

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
    dynamic data = serializer.Deserialize<object[]>(json);
    string emailAddress = data.emailAddress;
  }
```

The better way would be to create strong-typed POCOs for your return JSON data using something like http://json2csharp.com/ and then deserializing using **JSON.Net**  Library.

Comment: All answers given here works perfectly. Do you suggest that @Mohit 's answer is the best way to go ahead ?

Answer (score 3):

You can install [`Newtonsoft`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416621/3796048) Json.Net for retrieving value from a JSON string. You can simply create class like

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string formattedName { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

and then Deserialize it with simple one line code.

```
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(YourJsonString);
Console.WriteLine(ser.emailAddress);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution works as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
result={
         "emailAddress": "xxxx@xx.com",
         "firstName": "xxx",
         "formattedName": "xxxx xxxx",
         "id": "xxxxxx",
         "lastName": "xxxxxx"
        }
 var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var people = ser.Deserialize<object[]>(result);
foreach(var obj in people)
{
  Email = obj.emailAddress;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution works as well.