# How to fetch data form HTTP WebRespone in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

Hi i have a HttpWebResponse which recieves a JSON in the following format :

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "parent": "",
            "made_sla": "true",
            "caused_by": "",
            "watch_list": "",
            "upon_reject": "cancel",
            "sys_updated_on": "2018-04-18 06:30:19",
            "child_incidents": "0",
            "hold_reason": "",
            "approval_history": "",
            "number": "INC0010022",
            "resolved_by": "",
            "sys_updated_by": "admin",
            "opened_by": {
                "link": "https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441",
                "value": "6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441"
            },
            "user_input": "",
            "sys_created_on": "2018-04-18 06:30:19",
            "sys_domain": {
                "link": "https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/global",
                "value": "global"
            },
            "state": "1",
            "sys_created_by": "admin",
            "knowledge": "false",
            "order": "",
            "calendar_stc": "",
            "closed_at": "",
            "cmdb_ci": "",
            "delivery_plan": "",
            "impact": "2",
            "active": "true",
            "work_notes_list": "",
            "business_service": "",
            "priority": "4",
            "sys_domain_path": "/",
            "rfc": "",
            "time_worked": "",
            "expected_start": "",
            "opened_at": "2018-04-18 06:30:19",
            "business_duration": "",
            "group_list": "",
            "work_end": "",
            "caller_id": {
                "link": "https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/webservice",
                "value": "webservice"
            },
            "reopened_time": "",
            "resolved_at": "",
            "approval_set": "",
            "subcategory": "",
            "work_notes": "",
            "short_descripti
```

Now from this i need to fetch the value form state param. But i am not getting how to fetch it.

Comment: Probably [Retrieving value from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41338721/3796048) might help you.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply but that does not solve my problem.

Comment: @pratha1995 what do you mean by "that doesnt solve your problem?"  - please dont expect anyone here to code it for you , for you to "solve your problem".

Comment: i am not asking for code @Jaya 11

Comment: @pratha1995 it's helpful to know what exactly doesn't work to suggest a solution. Also, i would suggest you to post the code written so far.

Comment: The link I suggested does exactly what you wanted. I dont know what else you expected from SO. Another thing is even if we wanted to help you, Your **JSON** is truncated and thus not parsed.