# C#: How to trim a json string and put values into correct class

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string that I want to cut and put values into correct class. How do I do that in C#?

```
{
     \"First\":{\"FirstBool\":1, \"aString\":\"hello\"},
     \"Second\":{\"AnotherBool\":0,\"aString\":\"Hi again\"},
     \"Third\":{\"ThirdBool\":0,\"aString\":\"Hi for the 3rd time\", \"AdditionalString\":\"ADDITIONAL STRING\"}
}
```

This is how I've set up my class for taking JSON values.

```
public class First{

public static bool FirstBool {get; set;}
public static string aString {get; set;}

}

public class Second{

public static bool AnotherBool {get; set;}
public static string aString {get; set;}

}

public class Third{

public static bool ThirdBool {get; set;}
public static string aString {get; set;}
public static string AdditionalString {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: Cut how? What is the expected result? Also those bools aren't proper in the JSON.

Comment: what do you have after deserilization?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just use a JSON parser? It's designed for this kind of thing, you know.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Maybe "cut" is wrong word. I just want to store `JSON` data into correct class.

Comment: Then you make a class that contains those and deserialize with any JSON deserializer?

Comment: @Abion47 Aah I had no clue about that since I'm new to `JSON`. Do you have any good and easy guide for a beginner?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I see, do you have any guide/example that you can link? Never done it before.

Comment: Pick a parser and look up tutorials on how to use it. Newtonsoft/JSON.Net is the most popular one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON string in invalid in `First` it was like `"aString":"hello""` which should be `"aString":"hello"` So I hope and assumed it is a typo

You can install [Newtonsoft JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416621/3796048) and then create class like

```
public class First
{
    [JsonProperty("FirstBool")]
    public int FirstBool { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("aString")]
    public string aString { get; set; }
}

public class Second
{
    [JsonProperty("AnotherBool")]
    public int AnotherBool { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("aString")]
    public string aString { get; set; }
}

public class Third
{
    [JsonProperty("ThirdBool")]
    public int ThirdBool { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("aString")]
    public string aString { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AdditionalString")]
    public string AdditionalString { get; set; }
}

public class ClsResult
{
    [JsonProperty("First")]
    public First First { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Second")]
    public Second Second { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Third")]
    public Third Third { get; set; }
}
```

And Deserialize it like this

```
string jsonstr = File.ReadAllText(YourJSONFile);
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClsResult>(jsonstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your class will look like

```
public class First {
    public int FirstBool { get; set; }
    public string aString { get; set; } 
}

public class Second {
    public int AnotherBool { get; set; }
    public string aString { get; set; } 
}

public class Third {
    public int ThirdBool { get; set; }
    public string aString { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalString { get; set; } 
}

public class Result {
    public First First { get; set; }
    public Second Second { get; set; }
    public Third Third { get; set; } 
}
```

and then you can Deserialize your json using JavaScriptSerializer

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Result objResult =  (Result)json_serializer.DeserializeObject("<your JSON>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio, you could find out the class structure required for any json using Edit-> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes.

Create a root class which can be de-serialized to match your requirement.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public First First { get; set; }
    public Second Second { get; set; }
    public Third Third { get; set; }
}

public class First
{
    public int FirstBool { get; set; }
    public string aString { get; set; }
}

public class Second
{
    public int AnotherBool { get; set; }
    public string aString { get; set; }
}

public class Third
{
    public int ThirdBool { get; set; }
    public string aString { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalString { get; set; }
}
```