# Get value from JSON object in c#

Tags: c#, json, webforms

I am getting JSON response from a url and I am capturing it with following code in `jObj2`

```
dynamic jObj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultCheck.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
Response.Write("<p>"+jObj2+"<p>");
```

**Output** is:

```
{
    "method":"check",
    "trace":"1234/12345/123456f5",
    "order":{
        "ref":"2910730E3E90D40F59BC9B738E71EF7AD9DF679C93D34EAEADA6775216F12C13",
        "cartid":"1723873570174343",
        "test":1,
        "amount":"30.00",
        "currency":"USD",
        "description":"Descsdaff",
        "status":{
            "code":3,
            "text":"Paid"
        },
        "transaction":{
            "ref":"019463997038",
            "type":"sale",
            "class":"ECom",
            "status":"A",
            "code":"919514",
            "message":"Authorised"
        },
        "card":{
            "type":"Visa Credit",
            "last4":"0002",
            "expiry":{
                "month":3,
                "year":2017
            }
        },
        "customer":{
            "email":"email@email.com",
            "name":{
                "forenames":"James",
                "surname":"Senior"
            },
            "address":{
                "line1":"Denvour",
                "city":"Denvour",
                "country":"US"
            }
        }
    } }
```

How can i access individual values for

`carid`  `code`  `ref`  ...

I tried below code but it is give me error

```
var jsonData2 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultCheck.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    
Response.Write("<br> jsonData2['order']['description'].ToString() " + jsonData2["order"]["url"].ToString())
```

**Error Message**

```
  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An
 unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
 request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
 error and where it originated in the code.
 
 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
 set to an instance of an object.
 
 Source Error:
 
 
 Line 65:                 Response.Write("<br>"); Line 66:             
 Response.Write("<br>"); Line 67:                 Response.Write("<br>
 jsonData2['order']['description'].ToString() " +
 jsonData2["order"]["description"].ToString()); Line 68:  Line 69:            
 }
```

How can i access individual values from json object

Comment: I solved the problem, as i was referring to wrong value in following statement `jsonData2["order"]["description"].ToString()`

Comment: WHy -1, ca you explain

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this but I think, this is most relative answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4749755/5458824

Comment: I solved the problem as i was point to wrong object by mistake

Answer (score 1):

This might help to get the desired output

```
JToken token = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultCheck.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
Response.Write("<br> token.SelectToken("description") " + token.SelectToken("description"))
```

Comment: How can i address `code` which is in two places `status>code` | `transaction>code`

Comment: I would suggest you to use [`Json.Net`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40416621/3796048) for getting the values from this JSON Structure.

Comment: Am i  not using json.net `using Newtonsoft.Json;`